# Hide Link If DataBinder.Eval is null?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following ItemTemplate:

```
    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server"
                            Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Schedule.Employee.EmployeName") %>'></asp:Label>

                                <a href="#scheduleModal" id="scheduleLnk"
                       onclick="<%# "go('scheduleFrame',
'ScheduleFrame.aspx?type=project&id=" + Eval("ProjectID").ToString() + "')" %>"
                           data-toggle="modal">Unassigned</a>
                    </ItemTemplate>
```

I have a label and a link that opens a modal.

If: `DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Schedule.Employee.EmployeName")` is null, meaning the project is not scheduled, the lblUser should be hidden and the link should show, otherwise the link should be hidden and lblUser should show.

Is there some way to do this? I'm not sure scheduleLnk has a visible property.

Answer (score 4):

Yes there is a way:

```
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="lblUser" runat="server"
          Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Schedule.Employee.EmployeName") %>'
          Visible='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Schedule.Employee.EmployeName") == null ? false: true %>'> 
      </asp:Label>

      <a href="#scheduleModal" id="scheduleLnk"
           onclick="<%# "go('scheduleFrame',
               'ScheduleFrame.aspx?type=project&id=" + Eval("ProjectID").ToString() + "')" %>"
           data-toggle="modal"
           style='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Schedule.Employee.EmployeName") == null ? "display:block;": "display:none;"%>'>>
             Unassigned
      </a>
</ItemTemplate>
```